# VB.Net Query Syntax Error in MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(" UPDATE Items SET PartNo = " & PartNoTxt.Text & ", EqptDesc = '" & DescTxt.Text & "', Qty = '" & QtyTxt.Text & "', Pasok = '" & InTxt.Text & "', Labas = '" & OutTxt.Text & "', Tapos = '" & EndTxt.Text & "', SerialNumber = '" & SerialTxt.Text & "', CalibrationType = '" & CalType.Text & "', CalibrationDate = '" & CalOn.Value.Date & "', SupplierDue = '" & SuppDue.Value.Date & "', TodaysDate = '" & TodDate.Value.Date & "', Validity = '" & Validity.Text & "', Status = '" & StatsTxt.Text & "', DiOh = '" & DOTxt.Text & "', User = '" & UserTxt.Text & "', EMType = '" & EMType.Text & "' WHERE CTID = " & TxtItemCode.Text, connection)
```

I am using MS Access.
Here is the code which I am having problem with, it says "Syntax error in UPDATE statement.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` is a [reserved word in Jet/ACE](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html), so you must surround it with square brackets in your statement:

```
... & "', [User] = '" & UserTxt.Text & ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I got another error. Maybe you can help me? "No value given for one or more required parameters.". Same query.

Comment: Double-check your field names.  Most likely you have a typo or a field that's not really present in your table.

Comment: Done, it worked. Thank you so much mwolfe02. I'm having problems when I check query syntax here in VB. Its error message are not so detailed.